# how to use MD5 for authentication in OpenLDAP?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, amazon-web-services, openldap

I've installed OpenLDAP in AWS, everything was working as expected until I tried to authenticate a user, it asks me for the password and when I provide it, it says `Permission denied, please try again.` I've tried with the pass in plain text and MD5, but I don't know what's going on...I've modified the configuration in order to allow users to authenticate with passwords... If you need some files or something just ask and I'll update the question, thanks!!

## UPDATE:

This is for linux authentication

```
# This is the main slapd configuration file. See slapd.conf(5) for more
# info on the configuration options.

#######################################################################
# Global Directives:

# Features to permit
#allow bind_v2

# Schema and objectClass definitions
include         /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema

# Where the pid file is put. The init.d script
# will not stop the server if you change this.
pidfile         /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid

# List of arguments that were passed to the server
argsfile        /var/run/slapd/slapd.args

# Read slapd.conf(5) for possible values
loglevel        none

# Where the dynamically loaded modules are stored
modulepath  /usr/lib/ldap
moduleload  back_@BACKEND@

# The maximum number of entries that is returned for a search operation
sizelimit 500

# The tool-threads parameter sets the actual amount of cpu's that is used
# for indexing.
tool-threads 1

#######################################################################
# Specific Backend Directives for @BACKEND@:
# Backend specific directives apply to this backend until another
# 'backend' directive occurs
backend     @BACKEND@

#######################################################################
# Specific Backend Directives for 'other':
# Backend specific directives apply to this backend until another
# 'backend' directive occurs
#backend        <other>

#######################################################################
# Specific Directives for database #1, of type @BACKEND@:
# Database specific directives apply to this databasse until another
# 'database' directive occurs
database        @BACKEND@

# The base of your directory in database #1
suffix          "@SUFFIX@"

# rootdn directive for specifying a superuser on the database. This is needed
# for syncrepl.
# rootdn          "cn=admin,@SUFFIX@"

# Where the database file are physically stored for database #1
directory       "/var/lib/ldap"

# The dbconfig settings are used to generate a DB_CONFIG file the first
# time slapd starts.  They do NOT override existing an existing DB_CONFIG
# file.  You should therefore change these settings in DB_CONFIG directly
# or remove DB_CONFIG and restart slapd for changes to take effect.

# For the Debian package we use 2MB as default but be sure to update this
# value if you have plenty of RAM
dbconfig set_cachesize 0 2097152 0

# Sven Hartge reported that he had to set this value incredibly high
# to get slapd running at all. See http://bugs.debian.org/303057 for more
# information.

# Number of objects that can be locked at the same time.
dbconfig set_lk_max_objects 1500
# Number of locks (both requested and granted)
dbconfig set_lk_max_locks 1500
# Number of lockers
dbconfig set_lk_max_lockers 1500

# Indexing options for database #1
index           objectClass eq

# Save the time that the entry gets modified, for database #1
lastmod         on

# Checkpoint the BerkeleyDB database periodically in case of system
# failure and to speed slapd shutdown.
checkpoint      512 30

# The userPassword by default can be changed
# by the entry owning it if they are authenticated.
# Others should not be able to see it, except the
# admin entry below
# These access lines apply to database #1 only
access to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
    by dn="@ADMIN@" write
    by anonymous auth
    by self write
    by * none

# Ensure read access to the base for things like
access to dn.base="" by * read

access to *
    by dn="@ADMIN@" write
    by * read
```

Comment: (1) What service are you authenticating? Email(dovecot/posttfix)? Linux login? Http? (2) May need the slapd.conf.

Comment: @JohnSiu done, it's updated... this is for linux login...

Comment: Haven't have time to test yet. But did you configure PAM also?

Comment: @JohnSiu yes, I ran `sudo pam-auth-update`

Comment: Did you use [this guild](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openldap-server.html)? I am trying to go through it now.

Comment: @JohnSiu I used [this](http://www.ryazkhan.net/?show=ldap12) one, I don't know if affects that I'm on AWS using an EC2 instance

Comment: I have to go through them both. The approach seems different.

Comment: @JohnSiu the weird thing is I made it work before, in other box, like six months ago... and now it's not working in AWS

Comment: Did you modify `/etc/hosts` correctly? That seems to be the #1 check point.

Comment: @JohnSiu yes, with `127.0.0.1   ldap.testlab.dev ldap` cause I'm trying it locally

Comment: Your link, test method 1, does `ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=testlab,dc=dev -w test -f base.ldif` run successfully?

Comment: @JohnSiu yes, everything worked as expected until I ran `ssh rkhan@localhost` (I'm doing right now with the link you provided)

Comment: For `/etc/hosts`, add `localhost` back like following: `127.0.0.1 localhost ldap.testlab.dev ldap`. It needs to be there or many things may not work or act strangely.

Comment: @JohnSiu still nothing!

Comment: Do `grep apparmor /var/log/syslog` and let me know if you get any output from it. I am getting `apparmor="DENIED"`, which indicate communication blockage.

Comment: @JohnSiu I get `Jan 28 20:45:50 ip-10-243-91-178 kernel: [ 4240.549036] type=1400 audit(1359405950.534:24): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/slapd" pid=21836 comm="apparmor_parser"` a lot of times...

Comment: Yours is ok. I am re-doing my link.

Comment: @JohnSiu but it doesn't connect anyway...

Comment: (1) Are you able to create user in ldap? (2) Does the directory specified in `homeDirectory:` exist?

Comment: @JohnSiu (1) yes (2) no, but before, when I logged in, it just said the directory doesn't exist, I mean I did log in...

Comment: Do a test login, its ok if it fail, then do `tail /var/log/auth.log` and `tail /var/log/syslog` and check for related error message.

Comment: @JohnSiu I get `<= bdb_equality_candidates: (cn) not indexed` I've tried to fix that but with no success, using [this](http://muzso.hu/2010/04/26/fixing-bdb_equality_candidates-errors-on-your-openldap-server) and [this](http://ilostmynotes.blogspot.mx/2009/08/eliminating-openldap-uid-not-indexed.html), that in `syslog` and now, there is some new issue... in `auth.log` it throws... `pam_ldap: ldap_simple_bind Can't contact LDAP server`

Comment: ok, I have to continue later tonight. Should be able to put together some steps to fix it by then.

Comment: @JohnSiu ok thanks, I'm gonna try to fix it by myself...

Comment: Do following: `dpkg-reconfigure slapd`, then `dpkg-reconfigure ldap-auth-config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-auth-config)

### 1. Do `dpkg-reconfigure slapd`

```
dpkg-reconfigure slapd
```

Use following answers

```
Omit OpenLDAP server configuration? No
DNS domain name: testlab.dev
Organization name: testlab.dev
Administrator password: <password>
Confirm password: <password>
Database backend to use: BDB or HDB(prefered)
Do you want the database to be removed when slapd is purged? Yes/No (your choice)
Move old database? Yes (clean start)
Allow LDAPv2 protocol? No
```

### 2. Make sure you have libnss-ldap

```
apt-get install libnss-ldap
```

### 3. Do `dpkg-reconfigure ldap-auth-config`

```
dpkg-reconfigure ldap-auth-config
```

Use following answers

```
Should debconf manage LDAP configuration? Yes
LDAP server Uniform Resource Identifier: ldapi:///
Distinguished name of the search base: dc=testlab,dc=dev
LDAP version to use: 3
Make local root Database admin: Yes
Does the LDAP database require login? No
LDAP account for root: cn=admin,dc=testlab,dc=dev
LDAP root account password: <password>
Local crypt to use when changing passwords: md5
```

### 4. Now configure the LDAP profile for NSS:

```
auth-client-config -t nss -p lac_ldap
```

### 5. Configure the system to use LDAP for authentication:

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Make sure `[*] LDAP Authentication` is selected.

Comment: You will have to create ldap user  again after the above steps.

Comment: well... now I feel like an idiot, the only thing you use different is `LDAP server Uniform Resource Identifier: ldapi:///`, why it didn't work with `ldap://127.0.0.1`??

Comment: I am not sure either. I plan to do more research tonight. Also we should look for ways to limit ldap server connection to localhost only. The above config  is listening on all interface which is very unsecure.

Comment: well...I think I know how to do that... because I need to connect remotely...